# Get outliers from PCL sample consensus

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I am using the functionality for `SampleConsensus` provided by PCL as per the example here: http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/random_sample_consensus.php#random-sample-consensus

The question is, the implementation allows for the retrieval of ransac inliers through the use of `getInliers` this can then be easily transferred into a point cloud using the common function `copyPointCloud(in, inliers, out)`. I am interested in looking at the outliers. There doesnt seem to be functionality to return a list of outliers. If the inlier list is sorted then I could loop through the point list and check against the current inlier as so:

```
for i in point cloud
   if i == currentInlier
       currentInlier++
   else
       add point cloud (i) to new outlier cloud
```

But I am not sure that the inlier list is guaranteed to be sorted even though it seems like it would be created that way?

Also surely there is a native way to do this in PCL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost certainly want `pcl::ExtractIndices`. It is documented here:

http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/classpcl_1_1_extract_indices.html

You can see how it is used here:

http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/extract_indices.php#extract-indices

See in particular:

```
pcl::ExtractIndices<pcl::PointXYZ> extract;
...
extract.setInputCloud (cloud_filtered);
extract.setIndices (inliers);
...
extract.setNegative (true);
extract.filter (*cloud_f);
```